# Why is my program reporting incorrect time difference?

Tags: c++

I have written a program that performs a check after a given time period. It appears that the check is not being triggered, despite the difference in times is great than the monitor time.

Why is my program not entering the if block, and instead reporting the user time as smaller than the monitor time?

```
unsigned int monitorInterval = BATTERY_CONFIG->getBatteryLowMonitorIntervalSec(); 
unsigned long currentTimeInSec = getCurrentTimeInMillis() / 1000; 
unsigned long msgSentTimeInSec =itr->second / 1000; //itr->second contains previuosly stored value of getCurrentTimeInMillis

cout<<"Time: "<<monitorInterval<<"  "<<currentTimeInSec<<"  "<<msgSentTimeInSec<<endl;

if( currentTimeInSec - msgSentTimeInSec >= monitorInterval )
{
    TGS_LOG_ID( CRITICALINFO, D_ID, D_ID, "|es(Jitendra): %u User time greater than monitor %ld %ld %ld", clientObjId, monitorInterval, currentTimeInSec, msgSentTimeInSec);
    //Some operation here
}
TGS_LOG_ID( CRITICALINFO, D_ID, D_ID, "|es(Jitendra): %u User time not greater than monitor %ld %ld %ld", clientObjId, monitorInterval, currentTimeInSec, msgSentTimeInSec);
```

Output:

```
Time: 10  1581152987  1581152951
2020-02-08 14:39:47.671:CRITICALINFO:0,0,TCH:processTimeoutMsgForLowBatteryCheck:28557:|es(Jitendra): 5 User time not greater than monitor 10 1581152987 1581152951
```

Comment: Please format your code so it's readable. And this is C++, not C.

Comment: Hi molbdnilo, Sry for wrong formatting, code was looking ok in stack overflow editor but sooner I posted it, it appeared distorted way. I am posting on google drive and share the link sooner. Thank u for replay

Comment: Don't post a link, you will only get downvoted. Fix the formatting in the question.

Comment: I have attempted to edit the question into a more readable format, pending review

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1it8piM67yojhmiVtzID83yKqS05Ao8PD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What happens if you print `currentTimeInSec - msgSentTimeInSec`? It should come out as 36, but always worth checking. I notice too that unless `Some operation` returns from the function, you will *always* print the second message, which could confuse the output.

Comment: Hi Korosia, I have added the google link of code segment in comment. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1it8piM67yojhmiVtzID83yKqS05Ao8PD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I am going to check the eaxct diff here. that may help, thank for ur reply

Comment: depends on platform %ld might not refer to long long and some implementations do not support long long for C-style formatting. Likely you may have support of those https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cinttypes

Comment: @JitendraYadav Did you manage to discover the problem?